# Issues with pointers? Access violation reading location 0xfeeeff0e

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a reverse polish notation calculator using linked lists for my data structures class, and I can't seem to figure out the issue. Based on my amateur interpretation of what VS 2010 is saying (and others posts on SO), I've probable got some funky pointer (dangling, undeclared?). I can't really generalize from other posts where the same error is reported.

Exact debug output:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00a42504 in Assignment 1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeeff0e.
```

Here's the node class for reference:

```
class Node
{
    public:
    string optype_orVal; 
    int id;
    double num;
    Node *next;

Node(string input, Node *ptr=0)
{
    next = ptr;
    optype_orVal = input;

    if (input == "+" || input == "-" || input == "*" || input == "/")
        id = 0;
    else
    {
        num = atof(input.c_str());
        id = 1;
    }
}
```

I'm using `int id` as a quick way for my `polishCalc()` method to see if the node contains a operator or operand. At `if (temp->id == 0)` is where VS debugger is finding the error. I've tried tweaking declarations in the for loop and no luck. Note this is only part of `polishCalc()` method, and `operands[]` is instantiated privately.

```
string polishCalc()
{
    Node* temp;
    Node* hold;
    int i;
    int holdcounter;

    for (temp = hold = top, i = holdcounter = 0; i < 2 || temp != 0; temp = temp->next)
    {
        ++holdcounter;
        if (holdcounter > 2)
            hold = hold->next;
        if ( temp->id == 1)
        {
            operands[i] = temp->num;
            ++i;
            --count;
            if (top == temp)
            {
                    top = temp->next;
                    delete temp;
            }
                else
                {
                    hold->next = temp->next;
                    delete temp;
                }
        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you do `delete temp;` then won't your `temp = temp->next` blow?

Comment: 0xfeeefeee is a magic value, it means that you are using memory that was released.  Using `delete temp;` and then `temp = temp->next` will certainly turn out poorly.

Comment: I can reassign temp to another node. When I am deleting temp, I am deleting the node temp is representing, not the temp construct. This how my professor set up his destructor, and it complies/runs fine.